# RadListView: animate template selection change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and Javascript development in general. My background is Android.

**Background:**

As a test I try to replicate one of my old apps with NativeScript and have encountered a problem:

I use a RadListView with multiple templates. The correct template is chosen at runtime. The templateSelector uses a boolean variable to determine the correct one. (Imagine tapping a ListView item. When you do it expands and shows 2 buttons. You tap it again -> the buttons disappear.)

Now that works just fine.

**Problem**

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to animate the template switch. The new content just appears/disappear instantanously.

**What I managed so far**

I managed to animate the buttons when their template has just been chosen. I set their opacity to 0 and animated it to 1. Problem is: The necessery height for the buttons is reserved as soon as the template is chosen.

**Question**

Is this at all possible? If so how?

**Sources**

Expandable ListView items by manojdcoder:
https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/expand-element-radlistview/4268/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few built-in animations you could find in the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-animations) and working [examples](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/master/listview/app/examples/item-animations) in Github.

Comment: I looked into that and tried it. But I am not actually adding or removing items I just change their templates which, as far as I can tell, does not trigger the inbuilt animatons. On a side note: Am I correct in my assumption that you are the creator of that nice code I linked?

Comment: I believe change is also counted as interesting, you are removing a templating and adding different one. I had already tested it on my very own example you linked in the description, it changes the template with smooth animation.

Comment: I tested it with my Android 8.0 device. Is it possible that it only works correctly on iOS?

Comment: I too tested it on Android 8, Moto G5 Plus. Setting the animation type to anything other than Default gives a smooth expand animation - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Yh22j6&v=30 Since these components are not open source yet, I don't have much on it. Moreover updating template is not officially supported by the plugin, the [feature request](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/508) is still open.

Comment: Ahhh okay. I just set the itemInsertAnimation to Fade but not the itemDeleteAnimation. That was the problem. Thanks for your help!